# Linking Oracle with SQL Server on Windows Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, oracle, windows-server-2012, linked-server

We have been using SQL Server's linked server capabilities successfully for over a year to connect to Oracle. We've been doing this under Windows Server 2008. Today, we moved the same setup to an SQL server that was installed on a Windows 2012 machine.

When we connect with Windows authentication everything goes well. When we use SQL Server authentication we receive this error:

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I suspect that the account under which the SQL Server login is operating has no permissions to read the TNSnames.ora. However, how can I verify that?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating solution from comments to an answer:</sub>

> Part of the functionality of the tnsnames.ora file enables you to use simpler connection strings, but it needs to exist for every OS user (if it's being used there). I'd guess that you have "one" (a tnsnames.ora file) on the OS for your old OS user but not the new one.
>
> You should have a tnsnames.ora file for the new user, too.
> – [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458741/ben)   [Sep 22, 2014 at 12:28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973886/linking-oracle-with-sql-server-on-windows-server-2012#comment40670189_25973886)